# undefined method error but method is defined

Tags: java

Hi sorry I'm a beginner and still learning to code but I can't seem to find what the error is. I am told by my compiler that *the method size(int) is undefined for the type Board*. I have more code in Board which requires me to return size but I can't get past the hurdle of Board.size. Also thanks for all the contributions so far it really does go a long way.

```
    public class LOA{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    //First ensure the correct number of cmd line arguments.
    if (args.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: too few arguments");
    } 
    try {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }   catch (NumberFormatException nbfe){}

    try {
        int mode = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    }   catch (NumberFormatException nbfe) {

    }
    int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int mode = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    //Then check to make sure that a legal board has been selected.
    if ((size < 4) || (size > 16)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: illegal size");   
    }
    if(mode != 0){
        if(mode != 1){
            if( mode != 2){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: illegal mode");
                        }
        }
    }
    //Test mode
    if(mode == 0){
        Board.size(size);
        Board.newBoard(size);
        Board.displayBoard(0);
    }
    //Single-player mode
    //Multiplayer mode
}
```

}

```
    /*
      * This class implements the board. It stores an array that contains the 
    content
     * of the board, and several functions that perform operations such as 
    moving a
     * piece or counting the number of markers in a row, column, or diagonal.
     */
    public class Board {

     // The size of the board
      private static int size;

 // The pieces
 public static final int INVALID = -1;
 public static final int EMPTY = 0;
 public static final int WHITE = 1;
 public static final int BLACK = 2;

 // The board
 private static int[][] board;
 // Convention: board[0][0] is the southwest square

 /*
  * Create and set up a new board
  */
 public static void newBoard(int newSize) {
  /*--------------------------------------------
   * FILL IN THE CODE FOR INITIALIZING THE BOARD
   *-------------------------------------------*/
          //The Blank board
       int N = newSize + 1;
       int[][] board = new int[N][N]; 
       int i, k;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for( k = 0 ; k < N ; k++){
                board[i][k] = 0;
                }
        }
        //The top row of Black pieces.
        i = 0;
        while(i == 0){
            for (k = 1; k < N-1; k++){
            board[i][k] = 2;}
            i++;
        }
        //The bottom row of Black pieces.
        i = N-1;
        while(i == N-1){
            for (k = 1; k < N-1; k++){
            board[i][k] = 2;}
            i++;
        }
        //The left column of White pieces.
        k = 0;
        for(i = 1; i < N-1 ; i++){
            board[i][k] = 1;}
        //The right column of White pieces.
        k = N-1;
        for(i = 1; i < N-1 ; i++){
            board[i][k] = 1;}

 }
 //print the board
 public static void displayBoard(int i){

           i = 0;
           for (int C = 65; C <= (size+65); C++) {
               System.out.print((char)C);}
        while(i < size){
        int k = 0;
        while(k < size){ 
        if(board[i][k] == 0){
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.print(" ");}
        else if(board[i][k] == 1){
        System.out.print("W");
        System.out.print(" ");}
        else if(board[i][k] == 2){
        System.out.print("B");
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
        k++;}
        i++;
        System.out.println("");}

 }

 /*
  * Function that returns the piece currently on the board at the specified
  * row and column.
  */
 public static int getPiece(int row, int col) {
  if ((row < 0) || (row >= size)) {
   return INVALID;
  }
  if ((col < 0) || (col >= size)) {
   return INVALID;
  }
  return board[row][col];
 }

 /*
  * Make a move. Check that the move is valid. If not, return false. If
  * valid, modify the board that the piece has moved from (fromRow, fromCol)
  * to (toRow, toCol).
  */
 public static boolean makeMove(int player, int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) {
  /*--------------------------------------------
   * FILL IN THE CODE FOR MAKING A MOVE
   *-------------------------------------------*/

  return false;
 }

 /*
  * Return the size of the board.
  */
 public static int getSize() {
  return size;
 }

 /*
  * Check if the given move is valid.  This entails checking that:
  * 
  * - the player is valid
  * 
  * - (fromRow, fromCol) is a valid coordinate
  * 
  * - (toRow, toCol) is a valid coordinate
  * 
  * - the from square contains a marker that belongs to the player
  * 
  * - check that we are moving a "legal" number of squares
  */
 public static boolean isValidMove(int player, int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) {
  /*--------------------------------------------
   * FILL IN THE CODE FOR CHECKING A MOVE
   *-------------------------------------------*/

     return false;
 }

 /*
  * Count the number of markers (non-empty squares) in the specified row.
  */
 public static int rowCount(int row) {
  /*--------------------------------------------
   * FILL IN THE CODE FOR COUNTING THE MARKER IN A ROW
   *-------------------------------------------*/
        int rowCount = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (board[row][i] = 0; row < size-1; i++){
            if((board[row][i] == 1) || board[row][i] == 2) {
            rowCount++;
            }
        }
  return rowCount;
 }

 /*
  * Count the number of markers (non-empty squares) in the specified column.
  */
 public static int colCount(int col) {
  /*--------------------------------------------
   * FILL IN THE CODE FOR COUNTING THE MARKER IN A COLUMN
   *-------------------------------------------*/
        int k = 0;
        int i = col;
        int colCount = 0;
         while (i < size) { 
         if ((board[i][k] == 1) || (board[i][k] == 2)){
             colCount++;
             i++;}
           else {i++;
             }
         }
     return colCount;
 }

 /*
  * Count the number of markers (non-empty squares) in the diagonal that runs
  * from the north-east corner to the south-west corner of the board, and
  * that passes through the specified row and column.
  */
 public static int diagNortheastCount(int row, int col) {
  /*--------------------------------------------
   * FILL IN THE CODE FOR COUNTING THE MARKER IN A DIAGONAL
   *-------------------------------------------*/
  return 0;
 }

 /*
  * Count the number of markers (non-empty squares) in the diagonal that runs
  * from the north-west corner to the south-east corner of the board, and
  * that passes through the specified row and column.
  */
 public static int diagNorthwestCount(int row, int col) {
  /*--------------------------------------------
   * FILL IN THE CODE FOR COUNTING THE MARKER IN A DIAGONAL
   *-------------------------------------------*/
  return 0;
 }

 public static boolean hasWon(int player) {
  return Util.isConnected(board, player);
 }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the rest of the code for the Board class, so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: 1. Please update with the actual code of the size method, nobody can help you without the actual details. 2. Why is the size static? 3. size() is a very often used name in all kinds of libraries, might wanna rename that to something like setSize()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Board` class, `size` is a variable, not a method - it's defined as `static int size`. To access it, you do just `Board.size`. For example, `int x = Board.size` makes x equal to the board size. Or, you can do `Board.size = 20` to set the size - it's no different than saying `int x = 20`.

Your 'Test mode' does `Board.size(size)`. The parentheses mean you're trying to call the function `size()` in the Board class. And you're passing into that function the variable `size` you get from user input, so you're trying to call the function `size()` in Board and give it an int as the input. Thus, the compiler complains that there's no function in Board called size which takes in an int - "method size(int) is undefined."

Also, there's no reason for any of Board's fields to be static.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the code of your Board class, you're defining size as a member attribute, not a member function (method). therefore, you can't call it the way you're doing it.

If you want a function that returns the size, you should declare
    public class Board {

// The size of the board
      private static int size;

If you want a function that returns the size, you should declare

```
public class Board {

 // The size of the board
  private static int size;
int getSize()
{
return(this.size);
}
```